# Picking Certain Documentation with DOXYGEN

Tags: hide, external, doxygen, internal, sections

I would like to achieve the almost exact opposite of what can be
performed with command \internal. There exists a huge doxygen
documentation for a project already, but now I would like to pick out
a few blocks (functions, constants etc.) to create a very small manual
only containing the important stuff.

Instead of marking 99% of the comments as \internal it would be nice
to have a command like \external for the 1% of comments that need to
be exported in my case.

Something like disabling the "default section" (everything, which is
not part of a section) would work too, of course. Then I could use
ENABLED_SECTIONS...

Unfortunately the comments in question do not reside in one file only.
Furthermore those files contain a lot of other comments, which should
not be exported.

I already thought to move those comments into separate header files
that could be included in the original position, but this would mean
to restructure a lot and tearing files apart.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance,
Nico

Answer (score 0):

I think ENABLED_SECTIONS is the way forward, but there's a couple of things that might reduce the workload.

The first is to create a separate doxyfile for your particular requirement, then you can customise that without upsetting any master one.

In that new doxyfile explicitly list, in the `INPUT` file list, only those files that contain content that you need.  Chances are that it's currently set to pull in whole folder trees - edit that to cherry pick the individual files; not forgetting files that you may need to define the 'structure' of the document.

After that use ENABLED_SECTIONS with corresponding `@if <SECTION_NAME>` `@endif` markers to refine the selection to units smaller than a file.

Comment: This is what I meant: It is possible with ENABLED_SECTIONS (and by limiting the input sources). However, the problem still persists: I would have to modify the remaining header files in each "atom" (function, macro, variable, constant...) that should not be part of the result. Thus again it is not picking what I want, but picking what I do NOT want, which is much more work than the other way around.

Comment: @user3356415 OK, I think the code you've got must be arranged in a way I'm not imagining.  I'm out of ideas now.  Good luck.